# ReactJS Formik display error message in Red color

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik

In ReactJS i am developing one Class component and using Formik for validation.  I am able to do validation but error message is display as a normal color (black). How to add this error message inside any HTML element (span, div,etc..).

Below is the code to validation

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import { Formik, FormikProps, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

export class SubmitCase extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (values, {
        props = this.props,
        setSubmitting
     }) => {
        setSubmitting(false);
        return;
     }    
    render() {
        const formFields = {...this.state};
        return (
            <Formik
            initialValues={{
                subject: formFields.subject
            }}
            validate={(values) => {
                let errors = {};  
                if(!values.subject)
                errors.subject = "subject Required";
                //check if my values have errors
                return errors;
                }
            }
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            render={formProps => {
                return(
                   <Form>
                      <Field type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="subject" value={formFields.subject} onChange={this.changeEventReact}/>
                      <ErrorMessage name="subject" />
                      <button type="submit">
                         Submit Form
                      </button>
                   </Form>
                );
             }}
             />);
            }
        }
```

I am using  to display the message. Error message is displaying as a normal text(black color text). how to change it to red color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Form formik [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/errormessage) `<ErrorMessage>` component accepts a children prop as a function `children?: ((message: string) => React.ReactNode)`

so you can achieve what you want by return a component that wraps error message like this

```js
<ErrorMessage name="subject">
    { msg => <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{msg}</div> }
</ErrorMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can make css file for example - ErrorMessage.css
with body:

```
.validation-error-message {
   color: red;
}
```

And make js file for example - validators.js
with body:

```
import './ErrorMessage.css';
export const ErrorMessageWrapper = (msg) => {

   return (
      <div className='validation-error-message'>
         {msg}
      </div>
   )
}
```

And import, and use:

```
<ErrorMessage name="newPostText">
   {ErrorMessageWrapper}
</ErrorMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `component` props with your custom classes in ErrorMessage.

[Formik docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage#component)

e.g.

```
<ErrorMessage component="div" name="name" className="help-block errors" />

<ErrorMessage component="div" name="email" />
// --> {touched.email && error.email ? <div>{error.email}</div> : null}

<ErrorMessage component="span" name="email" />
// --> {touched.email && error.email ? <span>{error.email}</span> : null}

<ErrorMessage component={Custom} name="email" />
// --> {touched.email && error.email ? <Custom>{error.email}</Custom> : null}

<ErrorMessage name="email" />
// This will return a string. React 16+.
// --> {touched.email && error.email ? error.email : null}
```